# How to capitalize all strings in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, lowercase

I have a array of strings, but all the stings are written in upper case letters. Is there a way for me to make all the strings in the array to lower case, (and with capitalisation)

```
array = ["BOY","GIRL","MAN"]  
// func to convert it to array = ["Boy","Girl","Man"]
```

Is there a way to do this, without rewriting the content of the array with lower case letters. I have a very long array of strings in upper case letters.

Comment: Please don't add an already posted answer into the question. The place for anwsers is in the answers section, not within the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28690655/2303865

Comment: sorry, didn't find that post, my bad

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the map function like this:

```
let array = ["BOY","GIRL","MAN"]

let capitalizedArray = array.map { $0.capitalizedString}
```

Answer (score 7):

SWIFT 4:

The property capitalizedString has changed to capitalized.

```
let array = ["BOY","GIRL","MAN"]

let capitalizedArray = array.map {$0.capitalized}
```