# How to capitalize each word in a string using Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a function to capitalize each word in a string or is this a manual process?

For e.g. "bob is tall"
And I would like "Bob Is Tall"

Surely there is something and none of the Swift IOS answers I have found seemed to cover this.

Comment: var someString = "lol" ; someString.capitalized // "Lol"

Comment: A few others detailed this option below.  ;)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Are you looking for [`capitalized`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416784-capitalized)

> **Discussion**
> A string with the first character in each word changed to its corresponding uppercase value, and all remaining characters set to their corresponding lowercase values.

and/or [`capitalized(with locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414023-capitalized) (see also: [`localizedCapitalized`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414885-localizedcapitalized))

> Returns a capitalized representation of the receiver using the specified locale.
>
> For strings presented to users, pass the current locale (Locale.current). To use the system locale, pass nil.

Comment: I have not tried capitalizedStringWithLocale so I will play with it and comment back in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out the swift example on Apple's docs was mistyped which threw me for a loop (figuratively).

Comment: In newer versions of Swift, this is now just `capitalized`, `capitalized(with: Locale?)`, and `localizedCapitalized`.  In Objective-C the names are still the same as above.  _(The long story short is that in Obj-C it's still convention to suffix a property that returns an instance of that type with a short name of that type, e.g. `…String`— but not so in Swift and the Swift compiler automatically strips that suffix from property names bridged from Obj-C to Swift.)_

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson That's useful and comprehensive information which provides a much needed update to an out of date answer. You should feel free to edit answers you see like this to update them. :)

Comment: And what if you don't want the remaining characters lowercased?

Comment: @malhal so you want everything upper case? You can use `.uppercased`

Comment: @JamesWebster no, in your answer discussion section you quoted “ and all remaining characters set to their corresponding lowercase values.” I was asking what if you don’t want that? Ie just leave remaining chars as the case they already are.

Comment: There isn't a built in option for that - you'd have to split your string, capitalise the first letter of each element and recombine it.

Answer (score 40):

Swift 3:

```
var lowercased = "hello there"

var stringCapitalized = lowercased.capitalized
//prints:  "Hello There"
```

Answer (score 22):

Since iOS 9 a localised capitalization function is available as capitalised letters may differ in languages.

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
  "istanbul".localizedCapitalizedString
  // In Turkish: "İstanbul"
}
```

Comment: For Swift, it's `localizedCapitalized`, for ObjC, it's `localizedCapitalizedString`.

Answer (score 12):

An example of the answer provided above.

```
   var sentenceToCap = "this is a sentence."
println(sentenceToCap.capitalizedStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())  )
```

End result is a string "This Is A Sentence"

Answer (score 8):

For **Swift 3** it has been changed to [`capitalized`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416784-capitalized) .

> **Discussion**
>   This property performs the canonical (non-localized) mapping. It is suitable for programming operations that require stable results not depending on the current locale.
>   A capitalized string is a string with the first character in each word changed to its corresponding uppercase value, and all remaining characters set to their corresponding lowercase values. A “word” is any sequence of characters delimited by spaces, tabs, or line terminators (listed under getLineStart(_:end:contentsEnd:for:)). Some common word delimiting punctuation isn’t considered, so this property may not generally produce the desired results for multiword strings.
>   Case transformations aren’t guaranteed to be symmetrical or to produce strings of the same lengths as the originals. See lowercased for an example.

Answer (score 5):

There is a built in function for that

```
nameOfString.capitalizedString
```

This will capitalize every word of string. To capitalize only the first letter you can use:

```
nameOfString.replaceRange(nameOfString.startIndex...nameOfString.startIndex, with: String(nameOfString[nameOfString.startIndex]).capitalizedString)
```

[Older Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26306372/4056108)

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work for me. It just seemed to cap only the first word.  I found the thread that recommended this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with that seems to work but I am open to anything that is better.

```
    func firstCharacterUpperCase(sentenceToCap:String) -> String {

    //break it into an array by delimiting the sentence using a space
    var breakupSentence = sentenceToCap.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    var newSentence = ""

    //Loop the array and concatinate the capitalized word into a variable.
    for wordInSentence  in breakupSentence {
        newSentence = "\(newSentence) \(wordInSentence.capitalizedString)"
    }

    // send it back up.
    return newSentence
}
```

or if I want to use this as an extension  of the string class.

```
extension String {
var capitalizeEachWord:String {
    //break it into an array by delimiting the sentence using a space
    var breakupSentence = self.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    var newSentence = ""

    //Loop the array and concatinate the capitalized word into a variable.
    for wordInSentence  in breakupSentence {
        newSentence = "\(newSentence) \(wordInSentence.capitalizedString)"
    }

    // send it back up.
    return newSentence
}
}
```

Again, anything better is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of [Christopher Wade's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29261832/4833705)

```
let str = "my string"

let result = str.capitalized(with: NSLocale.current)

print(result) // prints My String
```