# In Swift 3 how to apply uppercase to only the first letter of a string?

Tags: swift3

```
var bookTitle = "god of the forest"
bookTitle.uppercased()  // "GOD OF THE FOREST"
bookTitle.lowercased()  // "god of the forest"
bookTitle.capitalized   // doesn't work
```

I get this error:

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'capitalized'

I want the string to be like this:

> "God Of The Forest"

Comment: after edit it would be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29261218/2303865