# Swift iOS Trying to change UITextAutocapitalization type on the fly

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have 2 `UITextFields` that have `UITextAutocapitalizationType` set to **`.sentences`**. I would like for the second `UITextField` to begin with a lowercase letter if the first `UITextField` does not end with a Period or Questionmark. I can programmatically set the first letter to lowercase, however, I have no way to enable the user to override it to capital and I want them to be able to do this.

The approach I took was if the first `UITextField` does not end with a period or question mark to set the second `UITextField`'s UITextAutocapitalizationType to **`.none`**. Once the user gets past their first character in the second text field, I set the `UITextAutocapitalizationType` back to **`.sentences`**. The problem I'm encountering is that it doesn't appear that the `UITextField` knows to update its `UITextAutocapitalizationType` while the user is typing. It waits until I leave the `UITextField` and return to it.

I have tried forcing a refresh on the second `UITextfield`, but that didn't solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to set the autocapitalization back to "Sentence" immediately after the user typing? The last character in the first text field is still not a '.' or '?' right?

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261218/how-to-capitalize-each-word-in-a-string-using-swift-ios

Answer (score 0):

Once the user gets past their first character in the second text field, then you need to set first character of each sentence capitalised programmatically in the following method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

}
```