# SwiftUI - Capitalise first letter

Tags: swiftui

I'm looking for format a text to automatically capitalise the first letter of every word

```
 Text("hello world")
```

Will show as:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift apply .uppercaseString to only the first letter of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306326/swift-apply-uppercasestring-to-only-the-first-letter-of-a-string)

Comment: not really. I'm looking for a solution on swiftui

Comment: Not sure what the difference is since it’s a string you are dealing with. I noticed I used the wrong link, this is the one I meant, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261218/how-to-capitalize-each-word-in-a-string-using-swift-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any Swift (NS)String API can be used also in SwiftUI

```
Text("hello world".capitalized)
```

Comment: It does, because it’s only available because of the SwifUI import; it’s misleading to call it String API.

Comment: Keep in mind that a `Text` with a `String` capitalized like this won't be automatically localized