# Make first letter Bold - ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am creating an application for Dutch and English language. So I add my string values to  Localizable.strings file. Now I want to change only one items first letter should be capitalized. For example, my string like this

**A.** I am in.

**B.** I am out.

I want to capitalize A. and B. and C. etc. I want to do it programmatically.

How can I do this in ios using swift as a language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift apply .uppercaseString to only the first letter of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306326/swift-apply-uppercasestring-to-only-the-first-letter-of-a-string)

Comment: Is it bold or capitalized?

Comment: Bold and capitalized

Answer (score 0):

Try to add attribute to string i.e.

yourString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
    value: UIFont(
        name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold",
        size: 18.0)!, 
    range: NSRange(
        location:2,
        length:4))

here you can decide location for word in string.Hope it will work :) Also please refer following link :- http://makeapppie.com/2014/10/20/swift-swift-using-attributed-strings-in-swift/