# How to bold first word of array?

Tags: arrays, swift

### var userComment = ["Time these make me.jenny is ","I can't she did it.", "Hey! what a great play made by brad", "I can't she .", "Time like make is a badass", "I can't it.", "She is a mean chose to place","Time me a badass", "Wow! I am just like jenny.I would shit", "I can't did it."]

first word of array in capital ex [TIME,I,HEY,WOW] other is same as written

```
    var attributeCommentArray:[NSAttributedString] = []
    override func viewDidLoad()  {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for comment in userComment {
            if comment.contains("") {
                let firstCharacter = comment.components(separatedBy: "").first ?? ""
                let myString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string:comment)
                myString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font,
                                      value: UIFont(
                                        name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold",
                                        size: 18.0)!,
                                      range: NSRange(
                                        location:0,
                                        length:firstCharacter.count))
                attributeCommentArray.append(myString)
            } else   {
                attributeCommentArray.append(NSMutableAttributedString.init(string:comment))
            }
            }
     //  self.navTitleWithImageAndText(titleText: "oneTwoThree", imageName: "")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
     //   chatView.makeCornerRadius(self.chatView.layer.bounds.height / 2)
        chatView.layer.borderWidth  =  1
        chatView.setCorner(borderWidth: 1, borderColor: UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, cornerRadius: 25, clip: true)
        self.tblView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        self.tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
        tblView.delegate = self
        tblView.dataSource = self
            self.loadXib()
                        }
    private  func loadXib()  {
         tblView.loadXibForCellResuse(LiveCell.identifier)
                      }
                      }
extension LiveChatVC:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource          {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return self.userName.count
           }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
  let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LiveCell", for: indexPath) as! LiveCell
  //  cell.userName.text = self.userComment[indexPath.row]
   // cell.userName.attributedText = myMutableString
    cell.userName.attributedText = attributeCommentArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell
          }
          }
```

[This is the implementation of code which is given by you please help it will not working in my controller it will print exactly the same text which is on the label,This is the implementation of code which is given by you please help it will not working in my controller it will print exactly the same text which is on the label]

Comment: So, have you tried something so far? Please provide it.

Comment: feeling help less

Comment: i don't understand why user give me minus reputation if they have gut then give the answer not reputation i don't want any reputation

Comment: Refer this : https://makeapppie.com/2014/10/20/swift-swift-using-attributed-strings-in-swift/

Comment: So you could start looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486761/make-part-of-a-uilabel-bold-in-swift/36486949 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331812/make-first-letter-bold-ios-swift

Comment: i already see this but i didn't find the right answer it is only for one string but i have an array and different words in the array i have to show different data on label

Comment: I think you have 2 question here.
1. How to get first word from each string in array. (If that's the case update your question)
2. How to make them bold.

For 2nd refer link shared by @AhmadF

Comment: i want to show whole data in label which is in the tableview and first word is bold and other is same as shown in array

Comment: if you know the solution for one string, you can iterate your string array with the same code, then append it to new array.

Comment: one string means "this is the string" THIS is get bold easily if there is only one string but stuck in array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486761/make-part-of-a-uilabel-bold-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code

```
var userComment = ["Time these make me.jenny is ","I can't she did it.", "Hey! what a great play made by brad", "I can't she .", "Time like make is a badass", "I can't it.", "She is a mean chose to place","Time me a badass", "Wow! I am just like jenny.I would shit", "I can't did it."]


var attributeCommentArray:[NSAttributedString] = []

for comment in userComment
{
    if comment.contains(" ")
    {
        let firstWord = comment.components(separatedBy: " ").first ?? ""
        let myString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: comment)

        myString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font,
                                     value: UIFont(
                                        name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold",
                                        size: 18.0)!,
                                     range: NSRange(
                                        location:0,
                                        length:firstWord.count))


        attributeCommentArray.append(myString)
    }
    else
    {
        attributeCommentArray.append(NSAttributedString.init(string: comment))
    }
}
```

Create Attrinbuted String array and use that array in uitableview cell label

cellForRowMethod

```
lable.attributedText = attributeCommentArray[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: how i created an attribute array and use that array in tableviewcell please help

Comment: i will do that same work in my controller but it will not work

Comment: let firstCharacter = comment.components(separatedBy: "").first ?? ""
Here should be " " (space)

Comment: @RahulMishra have you got it