# Unable to make a protocol for enum

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I am not very good with protocols, and I'm quite stuck right now. I am trying to make a protocol for an `enum`, which has a `name` property (or function if it needs to be).

This will allow me to get the name of an enum value, similar to conforming to `String` alone, but with the first letter capitalised instead. For example, what I *want* to happen:

```
enum Furniture: Named {
    case table, chair, lamp
}

Furniture.table.name   // Returns 'Table'
Furniture.chair.name   // Returns 'Chair'
Furniture.lamp.name    // Returns 'Lamp'
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
protocol Named {
    var name: String { get }
}

extension Named where Named: String {
    var name: String {
        let str: String = self.rawValue
        return str.prefix(1).uppercased() + str.dropFirst()
    }
}
```

This gives me errors, and when I try to correct them, another error pops up.

Right now, this shows me the following errors:

> Type 'Named' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'String'
>
> Value of type 'Self' has no member 'rawValue'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Isn't there a `.capitalized()` on String?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Didn't realise that, thanks! I got that part from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306326/swift-apply-uppercasestring-to-only-the-first-letter-of-a-string), where the first two answers are using this method (even though they _say_ it's for Swift 5).

Comment: That would be good for people who can't `import Foundation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums get their raw value via the `RawRepresentable` protocol, so that's what you should use when constraining your extension:

```
extension Named where Self: RawRepresentable, RawValue == String {
    var name: String {
        let str: String = self.rawValue
        return str.prefix(1).uppercased() + str.dropFirst()
    }
}
```

You also need to declare that your enum uses a `String` as the type of its `rawValue`:

```
enum Furniture: String, Named {
    case table, chair, lamp
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but is there a way to collapse `enum Furniture: String, Named` to `enum Furniture: Named`? Or any way to make `rawValue` not visible (like somehow using `private`)?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Furniture` enum to a string raw type, the Swift compiler automatically adds RawRepresentable conformance.

```
protocol Named {
    var name: String { get }
}

enum Furniture: String, Named {
    case table, chair, lamp
}

extension Named where Self: RawRepresentable, RawValue == String {
    var name: String {
        return rawValue.capitalized
    }
}
```

---

A Unit Tests to validate the Furniture enum,

```
import XCTest

class FurnitureTests: XCTestCase {

    func testEnumDisplayNameFirstLetterCapitlized() {
        XCTAssertEqual(Furniture.table.name, "Table")
        XCTAssertEqual(Furniture.chair.name, "Chair")
        XCTAssertEqual(Furniture.lamp.name, "Lamp")
    }

    func testEnumRawValue() {
        XCTAssertEqual(Furniture.table.rawValue, "table")
        XCTAssertEqual(Furniture.chair.rawValue, "chair")
        XCTAssertEqual(Furniture.lamp.rawValue, "lamp")
    }
}
```